# How do I change the text of text boxes in c# while storing references of them in an array or matrix?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, sudoku

Is there a way to change the text of textboxes in c# while storing references of them in an array ?

I've came across this problem while i was making a 9x9 sudoku game on C# widows form, I stored 81 text boxes in an array (tb) and then moved it to a matrix :

```
        tb[0] = form1.textBox1;
        tb[1] = form1.textBox2;
        tb[2] = form1.textBox3;
        tb[3] = form1.textBox4;
        tb[4] = form1.textBox5;
        tb[5] = form1.textBox6;
        tb[6] = form1.textBox7;
        tb[7] = form1.textBox8;
        tb[8] = form1.textBox9;
        tb[9] = form1.textBox10;
        tb[10] = form1.textBox11;
        tb[11] = form1.textBox12;
        .
        .
        .
        tb[80] = form1.textBox81;
```

moving the array (tb) to a matrix (tbmatrix) :

```
        TextBox[,] tbmatrix = new TextBox[9,9];
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                tbmatrix[i, j] = tb[c];
                c++;
            }
        }
```

I am going to put the random clues adding code just for if anyone wants to take a look :

```
    TextBox[] tb = new TextBox[81];
    Dictionary<int,string> col = new Dictionary<int,string>();
    Dictionary<int, string> row = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>, string> box = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, string>();
        Random initial = new Random();
        int index;
        int jindex;
        int val;
        int k = 0;
        while (k < 20)       //20 is the number of clues
        {
            index = initial.Next(-1, 9);      //a random number from 0-8
            jindex = initial.Next(-1, 9);     //same as above
            if (tbmatrix[index,jindex].Text != "")
            {
                continue;
            }
            t = new Tuple<int, int>(index/3, jindex/3);
            while (true)
            {
                val = initial.Next(0, 10);      //a random number from 1 to 9
                if(box[t].IndexOf(val.ToString()) == -1 && col[jindex].IndexOf(val.ToString()) == -1 && row[index].IndexOf(val.ToString()) == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            tbmatrix[index, jindex].Text = val.ToString();
            tbmatrix[index, jindex].Enabled = false;
            k++;
        }
```

now here is the problem the last code doesnt change the actual text boxes it only changes the references of them...
the only solution I've came across was to reassign the values to the original text boxes like something like that :

```
        form1.textBox1 = tb[0];
        form1.textBox2 = tb[1];
        form1.textBox3 = tb[2];
        form1.textBox4 = tb[3];
        .
        .
        .
        form1.textBox81 = tb[80]
```

So, any help ?

Comment: `initial.Next(-1, 9);` is a random number from **-1** to 8, not 0 to 8. The first number (min) is inclusive, the second number (max) is exclusive.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue, it may be because it looks overcomplicated.

Comment: Your example seems overly complicated for your question. If you have `TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();` and you assign `tb[0] = textBox1;`, then `tb[0].Text = "new text"` will set the `textBox1.Text`.

Comment: I think you do not understand how references work.  The array element and the form property refer to *the same thing*. It is *very important* that you understand how this works; if you do not then none of C# will make any sense. Study up on the difference between reference and value types.

Comment: @EricLippert I am sure i know what reference is but that array made my brain go funny thats why i thought it was was not referencing to anything at all but anyway thanks for making me see things clearer

Comment: @RufusL thanks im still getting the hang of using Random i dont know much about it

Comment: @BlakeThingstad I know that its over-complicated thats why im here

Comment: The question title makes no sense: You  have references, so you can work with the controls. b) this _moving the array (tb) to a matrix (tbmatrix)_ is wrong. Nothing is moved; you are copying references. _..the last code doesnt change the actual text boxes it only changes the references of them_ Yes it does change the textboxes. The actual issue seems to be that you lost track of how the array works and where you find the textbox you want. Most likely an x-y-problem. Forget about the array altogether! Start over by describing just what you really want to __achieve__!

Comment: @TaW thank you but i seems like i understood the problem wrong turns out my problem is how to display the changes done to the form and text boxes, update and refresh method don't seem to work

Comment: No update or refresh should be necessary at all.

Comment: @AhmadAl-Shayeb What TaW said describes why it is overcomplicated. You seem to be facing the classic "x-y problem" where you came up with an idea to fix something, but the real fix is to improve the design. An array to contain the textboxes and also a 'matrix' to contain them just doesn't make any sense. There should just be one data structure containing the textboxes. FYI, we're not trying to offend or anything, we're just trying to explain why we're having a hard time helping you.

Answer (score 0):

```
tbmatrix[index, jindex].Text = val.ToString();
```

Seems to work fine for me!

Also, change `initial.Next(-1, 9);` to `initial.Next(0, 9);`
Because (-1, 9) generated a random int from -1 inclusive

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer...but I'm not really sure what the question is.

Comment: i think its working for me too but the problem is its not displaying the change done to the text box

Comment: and about the random number i didn't know that it takes the minimum value thanks